# jquery force resize image within div

Tags: jquery

Looking for force an image size of an image within a jquery zoom div.

I have tried hard coding the height and width with no avail.

Here is the zoom live:
http://totallypleasured.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=1876

Click on the 3rd thumbnail to see the issue when you hover over the image within the div. The image is too small therefore it is repeated 4 times. I need to force the image size larger than the image zoon div to fix the issue.

here is the code that is generating the zoomed div.

```
zoomDiv = appendTo.append(format('<div id="cloud-zoom-big" class="cloud-zoom-big" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:%0px;top:%1px;width:%2px;height:%3px;background-image:url(\'%4\');z-index:99;"></div>', xPos, yPos, w, h, zoomImage.src)).find(':last');
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the issue I should be seeing when I click on the 3rd thumbnail & hover over the image?

Comment: appendTo is actually a jQuery method, but is that what you're trying to use, or did you just choose a really bad name for your variable ?

Comment: The issue is, the image is duplicated 4 times as the image is only 250px - i need to force the size of the image to be 500px so it only shows the image once.

Comment: @adeneo this is a contribution. It's not my coding - If it is a method, i would expect it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Just add background-size to the css of the div. So something like:

```
background-size: 320px 320px;
```

and to make sure it doesn't repeat use:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: @PaulWaudby You're welcome. Please accept answer so that future viewers can know what worked :)